# Customized data in Sales->Orders columns

Tags: orders, api, sales

[image]
My objective is to pull in tracking numbers for the orders (Already done) and take those tracking numbers, run them through the Canada Post API and take the result  (String) and add that to the column instead of the tracking numbers themselves.
What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: To be more clear, I want to take the tracking number from the database, run that through a function, and take the result of that function and place in in the column instead of the tracking number.